# ASP.NET MVC4: IE hangs with file upload and download in same request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, http-post

I have an elusive client-side problem with Internet Explorer. I am unable to create a webpage that uploads a file and downloads a file in the same request. My application lets the the user download a modified copy of a file they upload.

It's a simple form post event, with no AJAX involved, so the view has this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input id="physicalFile" name="physicalFile" type="file" />
   ...
```

The server response in the controller is pretty simple too:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(ReportDetailsModel model, HttpPostedFileBase physicalFile)
{
    ... 

    var fileStream = MakeReportFileStream(physicalFile.InputStream);
    return File(fileStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Results.xlsx");
}
```

However, Internet Explorer **hangs** after submitting the form. So bad that you cannot close Internet Explorer and must forcibly *"End Task"*.

Curious factors, including things I've tried, from most curious to least curious:

- Does **not** happen if I remove the file upload control from the form, the download works fine!
- Does **not** happen if I remove the download from the response; the upload on its own works fine!
- **Still** happens with all IE addons disabled
- Does not happen in other browsers (Chrome and Firefox)
- Does not happen on some machines (like mine) with the same version of Internet Explorer

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

- Being administrator on the machine has no effect
- Still happens when forcing the site into "Trusted Sites" and with minimal available restrictions.
- Installing IE11 **resolved** the issue
- In the cloud of confusion, I suspect some configuration forced onto these machines by the IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: install IE11.

I saw the issue both on IE8 and IE9. I have no data on IE10.